# Has anyone tried using one of those BAAS providers to create mobile games?

Tags: android, ios, multiplayer, server

I'm hearing a lot about different companies offering back-end as a service (BAAS) for mobile apps but it seems like none of them are very successful with mobile games. Is there any reason why not outsource the server to a provider.

The premise here is that the game does need a back-end to implement multiplier ans social functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion there are a few types of mobile games.

- **Single player / action / arcade puzzle -** these doesn't really require a server side anyway and you can go a long way with openfeint or gamecenter to implement the social functions.
- **Multiplayer / MMO / MMORPG -** These require a strong backend with very quick response times and the BAAS solutions are really not cut out for that.
- **Turn based Multiplayer / Resource Management MMO -** These are server based games that are ok with slower response times but require such a huge investment in backend that what the BAAS companies provide is insignificant.

Comment: One can make a multiplayer game with a very slow response, "The Witcher: Versus" is a good example.

Comment: I guess you are right. A turn based game or resource management MMO would be ok with slow response times.